# Issue in reading text in XML using python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I am trying to read the following XML file which has following content:

```
<tu creationdate="20100624T160543Z" creationid="SYSTEM" usagecount="0">
    <prop type="x-source-tags">1=A,2=B</prop>
    <prop type="x-target-tags">1=A,2=B</prop>
    <tuv xml:lang="EN">
      <seg>Modified <ut x="1"/>Denver<ut x="2"/> Score</seg>
    </tuv>
    <tuv xml:lang="DE">
      <seg>Modifizierter <ut x="1"/>Denver<ut x="2"/>-Score</seg>
    </tuv>
  </tu>
```

using the following code

```
tree = ET.parse(tmx)
root = tree.getroot()
seg = root.findall('.//seg')
for n in seg:
   print(n.text)
```

It gave the following output:

```
Modified
Modifizierter
```

What I am expecting was

```
Modified Denver Score
Modifizierter Denver -Score
```

Can someone explain why only part of seg is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be aware of the [`tail`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#tail) property, which is the text that follows an element's end tag. It is explained well here: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/web/etree-view.html.

"Denver" is the `tail` of the first `<ut>` element and " Score" is the `tail` of the second `<ut>` element. These strings are not part of the `text` of the `<seg>` element.

In addition to the solution provided by kgbplus (which works with both ElementTree and lxml), with lxml you can also use the following methods to get the wanted output:

1. [`xpath()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#xpath)

   ```
   for n in seg:
       print("".join(n.xpath("text()")))
   ```
2. [`itertext()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#itertext)

   ```
   for n in seg:
       print("".join(n.itertext()))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tostring` function:

```
tree = ET.parse(tmx)
root = tree.getroot()
seg = root.findall('.//seg')
for n in seg:
   print(ET.tostring(n, method="text"))
```

In your case resulting string may contain unnecessary symbols, so you can modify last line like this:

```
print(ET.tostring(n, method="text").strip())
```